# Given a Dataset<Row> is there an API function that takes a Row to add a column?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm looking for an API which would allow me to add a column based on a functions output that has access to the whole [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html). This would be similar to the ability to call [Dataset#filter(FilterFunction)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#filter(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction))

As an example, suppose I have the following DF

```
+----+----+----+
| c0 | c1 | c2 |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
```

I would like to be able to create a new column

```
df.withColumn("c3", row ->
  row.getInt(0) + row.getInt(1) + row.getInt(2));
```

And result in

```
+----+----+----+----+
| c0 | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 6  |
+----+----+----+----+
```

This is an over simplified example, the functions in question are much more complex and built at run-time.

Comment: you can always write your functions combining all the built in functions that meet you needs. if non of the build in functions meet your needs you can always use a udf function

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I'm just not sure on the API on how to do that. I see examples on how to write a `UDF` that passes an individual column, but I want the whole `Row`, is this possible (like `filter`)?

Comment: you've already got an answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder)):

```
map(MapFunction<T,U> func, Encoder<U> encoder)
```

and rebuild a whole `Row`, or combine all columns you need with `struct` and use udf:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

UserDefinedFunction f = udf(
  (Row row) -> row.getInt(0) + row.getInt(1) + row.getInt(2), 
  DataTypes.IntegerType
);


df.withColumn("c3", f(struct(col("c1"), col("c2"), col("c3"))));
```

but both methods will significantly less efficient than using standard SQL expressions.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using spark 2.0.0, this code does not seem to be compatible. I figured that I would need to use [UDF1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/api/java/UDF1.html), I just can't find the API to consume this function.

Comment: This is getting closer, it comes back to my original problem of how do I call the udf on the whole row?

Comment: As shown above - you use `struct` function and enumerate all fields needed by the `udf`.

Comment: Hmm, the problem I have is I don't know the shape of the dataset until runtime, the function is being compiled at runtime and is too complex for a SQL expressions. these get compiled to predicate functions and work perfectly for filtering and have proven to be more reliable than the spark sql equivalent. I have an alternate approach which is effective by using [Dataset#javaRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#javaRDD()) followed by a `mapToPair`

Comment: If you don't know the input `map` could be a better solution - you can derive new `Encoder` based on the old schema. In general `struct` [takes varargs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) (`struct(Column... cols)`) so you can create an array of columns on runtime (using dataframe schema) and pass it to `struct`.